# ArcGIS Network Analyst tool for Android?

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-android

I am trying to include the Network Analyst tool into an Android application. 
I have published the tool on ArcGIS Server and I integrate its URL address to use it. 
On the same time, I import a MapServer which display my network with all the layers needed to make NA work.

I tried to create a GeoProcessor and to input the tool in it and then execute it, but it doesn't work and I haven't found any clues on the web...

Does anyone has an idea about how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a geoprocessing service or are you trying to use the NAServer endpoints?  If you are trying to use the NAServer endpoints, I do not see any tasks for Route, ServiceArea, etc. in the API.  I do see a gp task, but you will need to be working with a geoprocessing service to be able to use it with the API, not a NAServer service.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer ! I will try it this way and create a GP service and see if I can deal with this.

Comment: So i have created a GP service and published it on my ArcGIS Server. It works well locally.But when I try to import it and use it, it simply don't work. Without any error... 
I assume that this should come from the parameters I give, but I don't know how to deal with this... 
Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have your GP serviced configured the recommended way?  Here is how ESRI says to do it:http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002v00000001000000.htm  Did you publish as part of an MXD or as a toolbox?